# watson machine learning api - token refresh 400 error

Tags: machine-learning, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I've successfully generated a token with the `GET /v3/identity/token` API.  I now want to be able to leverage the PUT API to keep the token active.

I am trying this curl command:

```
curl -X PUT --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '<token-value>' 'https://ibm-watson-ml.mybluemix.net/v3/identity/token' -v -i --basic --user <username>:<password>
```

I get a 400 error stating:

> For request 'PUT /v3/identity/token' [Invalid Json: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value at [Source: akka.util.ByteIterator$ByteArrayIterator$$anon$1@18bd12ef; line: 1, column: 3]]

The token returned from the get request has the dash character in it, along with other non-alphnumeric values.

Does the token from the get request need to be parsed?  what am I missing?

Comment: Not sure if you're aware of the swagger documentation. You can try there and maybe get hints on reformatting your curl command to work. https://watson-ml-api.mybluemix.net/#!/Token/put_v3_identity_token maybe you are formatting your JSON incorrectly or try using double quotes `"`

Comment: thanks, it was the -d param in the curl command.  the format is {"token":"<token>"}  and not just the token value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your content-type to `application/json`. But `-d` sends the Content-Type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which *maybe* is not accepted on IBM side.

But, seems like your JSON (token) are in the incorrect format.

The token value needs to be the following format (JSON):

```
{
  "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ"
}
```

And you need to follow the example of sent correctly the format:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X PUT \
-d '{"token":"yourToken"}' \
https://ibm-watson-ml.mybluemix.net/v3/identity/token
```

See the official [reference](http://watson-ml-api.mybluemix.net/).